# enqueue WP custom script first in line

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to enqueue a custom script first in line?
I need my script to be loaded as first 
(this enqueue function must go inside my custom plugin).

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#usage

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, but if you want your script to be loaded before one that depends on it, you could use dependencies param of `wp_enqueue_script` to pass your script. For example, your `example_script` script depends on `my-script`.

```
wp_enqueue_script('example_script', 'some_url_to_that_script', array('my-script'), NULL, true);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to suggest too... this is the way that WP provides for dependencies to be handled, instead of trying to change the load order manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need check is  add_filter priority option, try with zero

```
add_filter( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

Example

```
add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function', 0 );
```